# Return list of foreign key objects in django-nonrel using GAE datastore

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel

I have this simple model in django-nonrel with GAE datastore as the backend:

```
class SavedBooks(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', null=False, blank=False)
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='book', null=False, blank=False)
```

I want to make a classmethod to return a list of book objetcs from a certain user, so I am trying the following, but it doesn't seem to return anything.

```
@classmethod
def book_list(cls, user):
    return cls.objects.filter(user=user).values('book')
```

Any ideas of how can I do this?